# Update "value"= attribute of <input> on changing the value in UI or When enter Pressed

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an `input` field of `text` type in my HTML file. It Doesn't belong to any `form`. So i was actually trying to give input there and later take care of the input (In my case, make a `POST` request with ajax) by let's say collecting `.value` from these `input` field by referring it with `document.getElementById()`.But apparently the value i enter or edit on the UI there is not being "saved" in `value` attribute. As a result i am not being able to fetch those values later from js.
So is there any way for "saving" ui edited values in `value` attribute?

Comment: If you show your code it is easier to help

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide any code, but this snippet worked for me.

```js
function clicked(){
  var el = document.getElementById('input');
  console.log(el.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<button onclick="clicked()">click</button>
```